# Universal Links for iOS apps

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

Is there any way of opening a default iOS app from a universal link (for example the camera app).

If so, where can I find these public universal links?

Comment: Not possible it seems:- https://stackoverflow.com/q/3531585/4637057

Comment: ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115319/how-to-open-photo-app-from-uiviewcontroller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open Photo app from UIViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115319/how-to-open-photo-app-from-uiviewcontroller)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean this functionality?

```
func open(_ scheme: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: scheme) else {
        return
    }
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
}

// usage:
open("App-Prefs:root")
```

[Apple documentation about URL Schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899)

[Gist for iOS Settings](https://gist.github.com/tzmartin/b7019c22fc3152a0b2fe)